# Samsung galaxy Tab 3 won't show up in My Computer?

Tags: usb-drivers, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I am trying to root my tablet and it won't show up in My Computer when I plug it in. I have tried different ports and have tried rebooting the phone. I just purchased it 5 hours ago. I have Windows 7. I installed some Samsung drivers, but I am not 100% sure they are the ones I need (I got them from a guide).

I don't have an SD Card, but I do have 8 GBs of internal memory. I have Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 T210R with WiFi.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try google search: 'usbdeview' and download it.
Now delete all drivers with the Vendor ID '18d1'
Search Google again for: 'Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Drivers' and download and install, else use Google's USB Drivers: Search Google for 'Google USB Driver'.

Install them, and try and plug it in again.
On your tablet: Go to Settings -> Development Settings - > Tick USB Debugging.
You might wanna change your USB Storage to 'Charge only' or 'Camera' if possible. Else try to search Google for: 'Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 root'.

I hope I helped.